# getjson nothing happening

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Having troubles with the following code.  At this point I'd like to see the alert but not even that is happening.

```
$.getJSON('demo.js',function(result){
        alert(1);
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
```

demo.js looks like:

```
{ 
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 25
}
```

That alert isn't even popping up.  This is code taken from a web tutorial and it's not working for me.  I'm pretty stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if `getJSON` is picky about mimetypes. Try renaming `demo.js` to `demo.json`.

Comment: Have you gone to demo.js in browser? Had a look in Firebug (et al)?

Comment: Yeah, it looks find in the browser/firebug.  Renaming it didn't to anything :\

Comment: Your demo.js isn't json, its a javascript object. Try turning into a json-object. $.getJSON turns a json-object into a js-object.

Comment: So by simply changing the extension I turn it into a json-object?

Comment: @user972187 Your file should have a `.json` file-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debug purpose, you can do

```
$.getJSON('demo.js',function(result) {
   console.log(result);
}).fail(function (j, t, e) {
   console.error(e);
});
```

But I think your problem is either invalid json or header.

Answer (score 0):

In order to $.getJSON, you have to submit a json datatype

Using longhand $.ajax would work i believe if you were to omit datatype, but theres really no reason unless by your own restriction that demo sold be a js instead of a json file